# Scala, problem with a jar file

Tags: scala, jar

I haven't worked with java/scala a lot, so my problem might be very obvious, but here it is:

I'm working on a scala program, and I want to import from a .jar file (filename.jar) in a sub-directory. I figure that this will work:

```
import sub.filename._
```

But I get the error: "Object filename is not a member of package sub."

So I try simply moving the jar file to the same directory as the scala program:

```
import filename._
```

And I get: "not found: object filename"

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: are you adding the jar file to your classpath or path, i forgot what it's called in java/scala?

Comment: thank you! That seems to be the problem. Editing my classpath environment variable worked--I assume there's an easy way to alter classpath for the scope of the program

Comment: Both the Java and Scala executables take a -cp argument with a list of jars to add to the classpath. You might want to take a look at SBT if you're going to be using Scala as it streamlines much of this type of thing. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

That doesn't work. You import things from packages, not directories. If you have a JAR somewhere, you need to start Scala with the *classpath* parameter pointing to all JARs you want access to.

Answer (score 3):

ok, so i am going to change my comment into an answer:

add the jar file to your classpath :)