# Importing .jar files into Scala environment

Tags: scala, packaging, json4s

Even after reading: [Scala, problem with a jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429619/scala-problem-with-a-jar-file), I'm still a bit confused.  I am trying to import some packages into my Scala file, and the interpreter is not recognizing them even after adding to classpath.

One example:

I have the import statement:

```
import org.json4s._
```

I downloaded the .jar from here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json4s/json4s-native_2.10/3.2.4

and added to the interpreter classpath using:

```
scala> :cp /Users/aspangher13/Downloads/json4s-native_2.10-3.2.4.jar
```

Scala acknowledges the classpath:

```
Your new classpath is: ".:/Users/aspangher13/Downloads/json4s-native_2.10-3.2.4.jar:/Users/aspangher13/Downloads/jna-3.5.2.jar"
```

But still throws this error:

```
<console>:7: error: object scalatra is not a member of package org
   import org.json4s._
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!!

And as a followup, does anyone know where to find the package: JsonAST._?

Comment: Why not to go simple way, use sbt, drop libraries into ./lib/ folder and call `console`?

Comment: Alexlv is right, of course. But I think the problem you have is that you've only included JSON4S support, not all of Scalatra (or even its core).

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I just included that as an example of an import statement that wasn't working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go the simple and create a little sbt project.

**First step - create a project**

For your purposes you don't need a complex build. So just create two files:

**./build.sbt**

```
name := "name your project"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2" // or whatever you prefer
```

**./project/build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.12.4
```

The just go to the project root folder and call `sbt`

**Second step - add dependencies**

Open your `./build.sbt` file and add:

```
libraryDependency ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % "2.2.1",
  "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-scalate" % "2.2.1",
  "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-specs2" % "2.2.1" % "test",
  "org.json4s"   %% "json4s-native % "3.2.4",
  "net.java.dev.jna" & "jna" & "3.5.2"
)
```

**Step three - run the console**

Don't forget to reload sbt with `reload` task, and then call `console` or `console-quick` task. This should work.

But there are easier ways to do this:

1) Use gitter8 - [Scalatra gitter8 project](http://www.scalatra.org/2.2/getting-started/installation.html#toc_55) 
2) Read little into about [Scalatra sbt dependencies](http://www.scalatra.org/2.2/getting-started/project-structure.html#toc_53)

Comment: -1 Next time answer the question. SBT is not a part of Scala.

Comment: I agree, Sbt is not the answer, :cp behavior is confusing me too, please explain how it works in the REPL

Comment: @pferrel Well, i think that it was the answer for the topicstarter. I know how to solve problem using SBT, if you don't know this tool or don't know how to use it, you can always open a question and ask whatever you'd like to know.

Answer (score 5):

Still not sure how :cp works but if you execute

```
scala -classpath "list of jars colon separated"
```

then inside the REPL do your imports it should work

```
import org.json4s._
import org.xyz
```

However, when you try to use the classes you are likely to be missing transitive dependencies required by json4s and so we come back to the sbt example @ 4lex1v describes, which will handle this. Creating a little project and running `sbt console` will indeed greatly simplify this.

Seems like the -classpath and :cp are primarily meant to make your code available in the shell and then only if you understand all of the transitive dependencies, or have none.