# How to import play framwork jar in spark-shell in windows?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using windows machine and installed spark and scala for my learning. for spark-sql in need to process json input data.

```
scala> sc
res4: org.apache.spark.SparkContext = org.apache.spark.SparkContext@7431f4b8

scala> import play.api.libs.json._
<console>:23: error: not found: value play
       import play.api.libs.json._
              ^

scala>
```

How can i import play api in my spark-shell commnad.

Comment: You can create a build.sbt, which includes play as a dependency. And then load sbt console, and it should work. Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430164/importing-jar-files-into-scala-environment

Comment: @ShankarShastri. thanks a lot. in maven jar , we are providing <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ocpsoft.common/common-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ocpsoft.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
in mvn. how can do provide the same entry in sbt file.

Comment: Can you share the build.sbt, I can create an answer and post it back.

Comment: You should have something called as jars directory in your spark installation path. In my Mac, its under SPARK_HOME/libexec directory. Can you copy the required jar in that directory and restart your spark-shell ? This should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use other libraries while you are using `spark-shell`, you need to run `spark-shell` command with `--jars` and/or `--packages`. For example, to use play in your spark shell, run the following command;

```
spark-shell --packages "com.typesafe.play":"play_2.11":"2.6.19"
```

For more information, you can use `spark-shell -h`. I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot ulubeyn. I think it is short term solution in spark-shell. How can i do permanent one like pom.xml

Comment: I can recommend another way but I need to know one thing; do you want to use `spark-shell` or just `spark`?

Comment: I recommend you to use SBT for Scala projects, because it is default build tool. Also, you can do lots of things with SBT files, like creating your own `SparkContext` as described [here](https://sanori.github.io/2017/06/Using-sbt-instead-of-spark-shell/).

Comment: If you are developing a Spark application, it is better to use `build.sbt` which includes Spark and Play as a dependency, because you can make your own configurations, or create your jar to run repetitively in cloud/somewhere else. If you are just developing a simple Spark job, create a `.scala` file and run it with `spark-shell` specifying `play` as a dependency.